# Efficient model traversal (joins) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a rails app with a set of relations. Users read and rank books, and organizations are collections of users, who collectively have a list of books they've read/rated:

```
class Organization
  has_many :users, through: memberships
end
```

```
class Membership
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :user
end
```

```
class User
  has_many :books, through: :readings
  has_many :organizations, through: :memberships
end
```

```
class Readings
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book
end
```

```
class Book
  has_many :readings
end
```

I would like to, in one query, find all the books that an organization has read and rated. Something like:

```
organization.members.books
```

I would ideally like to use this with will_paginate and sort by the ratings on the Readings class. Any idea how to do this without custom SQL?

Comment: Shouldn't the relation in Organization be `has_many :users, through: :memberships` (or `has_many :members, through: :memberships, source: :user`)?

Comment: Yes, updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following relations:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
  has_many :books, -> { uniq }, through: :users
end
```

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :user
end
```

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :readings
  has_many :organizations, through: :memberships
  has_many :books, through: :readings
end
```

```
class Reading < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book
end
```

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :readings
  has_many :users, through: :readings
  has_many :organizations, -> { uniq }, through: :users
end
```

Now you can call `@organization.books` to get all books for a specific organization.

I don't know exactly how you handle ratings, but you could add a scope called `rated` to your `Book` model and then call `@organization.books.rated` to get all rated books for a specific organization. Here is an example of what that scope might look like:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :readings
  has_many :users, through: :readings
  has_many :organizations, through: :users

  scope :rated, -> { where.not(rating: nil) }
  scope :rated_above, ->(rating) { where('rating >= ?', rating) }
  scope :rated_below, ->(rating) { where('rating <= ?', rating) }
end
```

That is just an example assuming you use some integer based rating system where a `nil` rating means it is unrated. I also threw in the `rated_above` and `rated_below` scopes, which you may or may not find useful. You could use them like `@organization.books.rated_above(6)` to only get the books with a rating greater than or equal to 6. Again, these are just examples, you might need to change them to work with your rating implementation.

---

**Update**

In the case where your ratings are stored on the `Reading` model, you can change your `Book` model to the following:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :readings
  has_many :users, through: :readings
  has_many :organizations, -> { uniq }, through: :users

  scope :rated, -> { with_ratings.having('COUNT(readings.rating) > 0') }
  scope :rated_above, ->(rating) { with_ratings.having('average_rating >= ?', rating) }
  scope :rated_below, ->(rating) { with_ratings.having('average_rating <= ?', rating) }

  private

  def self.with_readings
    includes(:readings).group('books.id')
  end

  def self.with_ratings
    with_readings.select('*, AVG(readings.rating) AS average_rating')
  end
end
```

I am not sure if there is a simpler approach, but it gets the job done. Now the scopes should work as expected. Additionally, you can sort by rating like this: `@organization.books.rated.order('average_rating DESC')`

Comment: The rating isn't on the book itself, but instead on the Reading. It is per-user, rather than per-book. This allows some orgs to rate a book highly that others rate less well. It looks here like you've assumed it is on book. I will see if this works with that scope on the reading though.

Comment: Yeah, that would make more sense. Check out the update I made to my answer and see if that works.

Comment: There is one problem with this, which is that it returns a list with duplicates. You get one book for each reading. I am not able to fix this with my few attempts to distinct the select. Perhaps you have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This should give you all the books that an organization has read in one query. Not sure how your ratings are implemented.

```
Book.joins(:readings => {:user => :memberships})
  .where(:readings => {:users => {:memberships => {:organization_id => @organization.id}}})
```